# Constructor for a test class in Google Test

Tags: c++, googletest

```
namespace {

using namespace std;
// Declare the google test case
class InjectorTest : public ::testing::Test {

std::shared_ptr<MyData>> m_reader;
public:
    static void SetUpTestCase() {

    }
    static void TearDownTestCase() {

    }

    InjectorTest()
    {
        //Create Reader code here !!!!
        m_reader = CreateReader();

    }
    std::shared_ptr<DDSTopicReader<MyData>> getXMLReader() {

        return m_reader;
    }
};

TEST_F(InjectorTest, CreateReaderAndGetTopic) {
        auto reader = getXMLReader();
        std::string topic_name = reader->getTopicName();
        EXPECT_EQ(topic_name, "test_topic");
}
}; // anonymous namespace
```

My questions is

1) When I run the test case `CreateReaderAndGetTopic` does the `Constructor` of InjectorTest gets called before executing the test case? Or should it be called explictly ?

2) Should my class `InjectorTest` have a constructor or should the code inside the constructor be moved to `SetUpTestCase`.

Answer (score 4):

Let's mention first that the static class members `SetUpTestCase` and
`TearDownTestCase` have been renamed respectively to [`SetUpTestSuite` and `TearDownTestSuite`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#sharing-resources-between-tests-in-the-same-test-suite)
since googletest v1.8. See [Beware of the nomenclature](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#beware-of-the-nomenclature)

They did that because the names `SetUpTestCase` and `TearDownTestCase` were grossly
misleading. They suggest functions that will be run in every *case of a test* that
is derived from the fixture class in which they are defined, which they weren't.
`SetUpTestCase` was in fact run *before the first of all tests derived from the fixture*
(and still is, if you have an older googletest installation), and `TearDownTestCase`
was run *after the last of all tests derived from the fixture.*

As of googletest 1.8, all of the tests that derived from a fixture - which we'd
naturally call its *test cases* - are collectively regarded as a *test suite*;
so the set-up function that runs before all of them is now called `SetUpTestSuite`
and the tear-down function that runs after of them is called `TearDownTestSuite`.
I will stick with the new improved names as I have the latest rev of googletest.

Look at this gtest code that demonstrates the calling order of a fixture's
constructor and destructor, `SetUp` and `TearDown`, `SetUpTestSuite` and `TearDownTestSuite`:

**gtester.cpp**

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

struct fixture : ::testing::Test
{
    fixture() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    ~fixture() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    void SetUp() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    void TearDown() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    static void SetUpTestSuite() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    static void TearDownTestSuite() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

TEST_F(fixture, One) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
}

TEST_F(fixture, Two) {
    ASSERT_NE(1,0);
}

TEST_F(fixture, Three) {
    ASSERT_LT(1,2);
}
```

You can get a useful peek under the hood if you just preprocess this
file (and preferably, pipe through a pretty-printer) and look at what comes out:

```
$   g++ -E -P gtester.cpp | clang-format > gtester.ii
```

In `gtester.ii` you'll be able to find:

```
...
class fixture_One_Test : public fixture {
public:
  fixture_One_Test() {}
private:
  virtual void TestBody();
  static ::testing::TestInfo *const test_info_ __attribute__((unused));
  fixture_One_Test(fixture_One_Test const &) = delete;
  void operator=(fixture_One_Test const &) = delete;
};
::testing::TestInfo *const fixture_One_Test::test_info_ =
    ::testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(
        "fixture", "One", nullptr, nullptr,
        ::testing::internal::CodeLocation("gtester.cpp", 31),
        (::testing::internal::GetTypeId<fixture>()),
        ::testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<fixture>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(),
        ::testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<
            fixture>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite(),
        new ::testing::internal::TestFactoryImpl<fixture_One_Test>);
void fixture_One_Test::TestBody() {
  switch (0)
  case 0:
  default:
    if (const ::testing::AssertionResult gtest_ar =
            (::testing::internal::EqHelper<
                decltype(::testing::internal::IsNullLiteralHelper(
                    1, ::testing::internal::TypeIsValidNullptrConstant<decltype(
                           1)>()))::value>::Compare("1", "1", 1, 1)))
      ;
    else
      return ::testing::internal::AssertHelper(
                 ::testing::TestPartResult::kFatalFailure, "gtester.cpp", 32,
                 gtest_ar.failure_message()) = ::testing::Message();
}
...
```

That is what the test case:

```
TEST_F(fixture, One) {
    ASSERT_EQ(1,1);
}
```

expands to after preprocessing. When googletest runs test case `fixture.One`:

- It constructs a new instance of `fixture_One_Test` - which by inheritance, is
  a new instance of `fixture`.
- The base `fixture` constructor is called.
- The derived `fixture_One_Test` constructor is called. (But it's empty.)
- Googletest calls `fixture::Setup()` through the `fixture_One_Test` instance.
- It calls `fixture_One_Test::TestBody()` through the `fixture_One_Test` instance,
  which executes the payload of the test case.
- It calls calls `fixture::TearDown()` through the `fixture_One_Test` instance.
- It destroys the `fixture_One_Test` instance, which -
- Calls the `fixture_One_Test` destructor, which simply -
- Calls the `fixture` destructor.

Similarly for `fixture_Two_Test` and `fixture_Three_Test`.

And just before all of that, googletest calls `fixture::SetupTestSuite`, if it's
is defined.

And just after all of that, googletest calls `fixture::TearDownTestSuite`, if it's
is defined.

Now let's see that in action:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -o gtester gtester.cpp -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
$ ./gtester 
Running main() from /home/imk/Downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 3 tests from fixture
static void fixture::SetUpTestSuite()
[ RUN      ] fixture.One
fixture::fixture()
virtual void fixture::SetUp()
virtual void fixture::TearDown()
virtual fixture::~fixture()
[       OK ] fixture.One (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] fixture.Two
fixture::fixture()
virtual void fixture::SetUp()
virtual void fixture::TearDown()
virtual fixture::~fixture()
[       OK ] fixture.Two (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] fixture.Three
fixture::fixture()
virtual void fixture::SetUp()
virtual void fixture::TearDown()
virtual fixture::~fixture()
[       OK ] fixture.Three (0 ms)
static void fixture::TearDownTestSuite()
[----------] 3 tests from fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 3 tests from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 3 tests.
```

`SetUpTestSuite()` and `TearDownTestSuite()` each run just once. The constructor,
destructor, `SetUp()` and `TearDown()` each run 3 times = the number of test cases
in the test suite.

So to your two questions:

> When I run the test case CreateReaderAndGetTopic does the Constructor of InjectorTest gets called before executing the test case? Or should it be called explictly ?

The `InjectorTest` constructor is necessarily called to construct an instance of the class `CreateReaderAndGetTopic_InjectorTest_Test`,
which Googletest does for you. It is called before `SetUp()`, which is called before `TestBody()`, which is the payload of the test case.

> Should my class InjectorTest have a constructor...

`InjectorTest` *will have* a constructor, either by default or as defined by you; so you're
wondering whether you should define one.

You should define one if you have something to do that needs to be done *anew* in preparation
for *each* test case, and that had better be done before the `SetUp()` for each test case.

> ... or should the code inside the constructor be moved to SetUpTestCase?

The code you have inside the constructor:

```
m_reader = CreateReader();
```

should be moved out to `SetUpTestCase` - a.k.a `SetUpTestSuite` - if it is something
that does *not* need to be done anew in preparation for each test case but needs to be
done once *just before* all test cases of `InjectorTest`.

As it stands, you *cannot* move that constructor code into `SetUpTestSuite` because it initializes a non-static
class member of `InjectorTest`, `m_reader`. But do you in fact need or want a new `XMLReader`
to be created by `CreateReader()` for each test case? Only you can decide.

If you do want to create a new reader for each test case, then you face the choice
of creating it in the constructor or in `SetUp()`. Here you can be guided by the
Googletest FAQ [Should I use the constructor/destructor of the test fixture or SetUp()/TearDown()?](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure your test cases in a fixture have the same setup, you should implement the `SetUp` and `TearDown` methods (notice the case)

Your `InjectorTest` fixture only gets constructed once, but the `SetUp` step (resp. the `TearDown` step) will be run before (resp. after) your test case is executed.

The constructor should only deal with things that should be only done once (if any), any behavior you want to enforce for your test cases should go in these 2 methods. In your example, if the `m_reader` member can be shared across all your test cases, you can initialize it in the constructor like you did.

To sumup, here is the sequence of operations that will be run:

1. `InjectorTest::InjectorTest()`: test fixture is constructed
2. For each test case:

   1. `InjectorTest::SetUp()`: setup for test case
   2. Test case is run (in your example `InjectorTest::CreateReaderAndGetTopic`)
   3. `InjectorTest::TearDown()`: setup is undone for next case
3. `InjectorTest::~InjectorTest()`: destruction of the fixture object

Comment: by test fixture you mean the `Class InjectorTest` ?